# Should papers presented at local conferences be put in list of publications?

Tags: publications

I have two papers presented at state and national level conferences. These conference proceedings were not published in any journal. Now, should I list these papers in my list of publications or not?

Comment: I did not notice that I ask some question like you exactly after yours : http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/34950/put-the-non-english-conference-article-on-google-scholar-or-academia-edu-or-rese

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> These conference proceedings were not published in any journal.

Were they published at all?  If there were no proceedings, then they don't count as publications, because nothing was actually published.  (You could still list them as talks rather than publications.)  If there were official proceedings in which other people can read and cite the paper (not just an abstract) even after the conference is over, then it's a form of publication, regardless of whether the proceedings appeared in a journal or as a stand-alone volume.

There may be other considerations you should take into account when including this material in your CV.  For example, were the papers peer reviewed?  Does your field consider them to be archival publications?  However, these are more of an issue of how meaningful the publications are, rather than whether they count as publications in the first place.

Comment: There was a proceeding booklet given to all participants of the conference. Your are right in saying that their meaningfulness is more important!

Comment: Was this booklet just a collection of abstracts or did it include actual papers?

Comment: @Brian Brochers Aah! Thanks for asking! Only abstracts were published.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a little on your field. What do other people in your field do?

But maybe list it as a presentation rather than a publication.

Because in some fields, conference handouts are freely available on the personal websites of the presenters and it's totally acceptable to cite other people's conference handouts.

Comment: Definitely list it as a presentation rather than a publication. If nothing was published, it isn't a publication. By definition.