# Should I put my papers which are not written in English on my social-media profile?

Tags: publications, language, google-scholar, social-media

Is it OK to put my non English internal conference or journal paper on my social media profiles such as Google Scholar, Academia, Research Gate, etc? and also, should I translate their title and other information into English?

Comment: You can't "put" your paper on Google Scholar. It's an index that lists papers available elsewhere.

Comment: You can "manually" add papers into Google Scholar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is. English is a *lingua franca*, but that doesn't mean that all scholarly literature **must** be in English. Make sure your paper is in a institutional or disciplinary repository, if you like the idea of your paper to be *open access*. Translate it, as Davidmh suggests, to make it even more available.

Regarding indexing in Google Scholar, that depends by the site you archive your paper into. You can make [some arrangements to be indexed](http://scholar.google.it/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#indexing), but in my experience even if you suggest resources to GS you cannot be sure you'll be.

Answer (score 4):

It is your work, you can of course take credit for it. Translating it will help the international audience to get a feeling of what you do; nevertheless, in the interest of archiving, you should keep the original title next to it. In case it is not clear, indicate that the original paper was in another language.